# How to disable root permission on terminal (manjaro)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, sudo, root, manjaro

I'm new on linux and I just installed Manjaro on my laptop.

Looking for informations and installing the softwares and extensions that I need (such as Kdenlive, libreoffice and others).

Somehow, I don't remember how, I installed some of these applications by the terminal on myu manjaro. By doing that, I end up with root and I enable (or disabled it or something of the kind) that daily, it seems that someone else get access on my computer. It's like someone else has controls and my mouse arrow moves not by my command, it keeps moving randomly.

Looking for solutions on the internet, I end up here and in other questions, requesting precisely the opposite of my doubt (It's what I think it should be done), I end up in the page below. But I'm not 100% sure what command to use.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Sudo

Anyone could help me with this issue. Because I'm loving to use Manjaro and I didn't want to resintall and begin all the process again.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be possible for an outsider or malware to cause your mouse to move randomly, unless someone is hacking your system just to get your attention, or you have enabled screen sharing (such as VNC or RDP), that is the least likely thing they would do, and it would be more work to make your mouse move than steal or damage all your files without you noticing (until it was too late).

Random mouse movement is much more likely to be caused by hardware issues, such as poor detection and filtering of normal vibrations by the mouse driver or failing mouse hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel someone takes control from outside, the best thing is to install `ufw` and type:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw enable
```

Sudo will permit a logged user which is in your sudoers group to be root. But if your host is attacked, there can be background programs (daemon) which are running without needing sudo.

Note that if your system is compromised, it can be easier to save your data and reinstall the OS. Finding a malware can be as difficult as finding a needle in a haystack. Some programs can help (trivy, chkrootkit…), but they can’t be definitive answers.

NB : You may need sudo to install more software or setting something. Then, excepted if you can log directly as root through `su`, it is a bad thing to disable `sudo`.